# How to call an existing defined javascript function with an prototypejs ajax onSuccess event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

All the documentation i can find has you defining the actual function to call within the ajax constructor like this

```
new Ajax.Request('/your/url', {
   onSuccess: function(response) {
   // Handle the response content...
}
});
```

But my code throws an error saying "UnCaught typeError: undefined is not a function"
Here is my code trying to call the existing function pullComments().

```
    function addComment(){
    //  Stringify json 
    var commentStr = $('#commentBox').value;
    var JSONObj = { "dealID" : dealID,
                    "username" : "default",
                    "comment" : commentStr };
    JSONObj = JSON.stringify(JSONObj);
    var JSONComment = encodeURIComponent(JSONObj);
    new Ajax.request("php/savecomment", 
    {
        method: 'POST',
        parameters: "comment=" + JSONComment,
        onSuccess: pullComments()
    });
}

function pullComments(){
    //  Grab the comments for the deal
    var xmlhttp
            ****
```

Comment: remove the `()` from the end of `onSuccess: pullComments()`

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
onSuccess: pullComments
```

You want to pass the implementation of the function to 'onSuccess' rather than the result of the function.